# Essa função não deveria retornar um bool em vez de uma Pizza?

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando react e me deparei com a seguinte expressão:

`{this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}`

Essa expressão em resumo irá imprimir uma pizza para cada palavra inserida no texto:

Segue o exemplo:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input

Bem a duvida não é sobre react mas sim sobre o que será retornado nessa função:

`(word) => word && ''`

Esta função recebe uma palavra `word` e se a palavra for válida então será retornada uma pizza

Mas se caso eu fazer isto:

`(word) => '' && word`

Será retornada a palavra e não uma pizza.

Mas essa condição não deveria retornar um bool, já que se trata de uma condição booleana? E porque sempre a ultima clausula que é retornada? Ou isso tem a ver com a função Map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador `&&` no Javascript avalia a primeira expressão e sendo ela algo que possa ser considerador verdadeiro, retorna o valor da segunda expressão.

Por exemplo:

```js
console.log('a' && 'b' && 'c');
```

É considerado como falso os valores 0, 0.0, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''` e `NaN`. O resto é considerado como verdadeiro.

Comment: Então é uma especie de recursão? No caso do if ele verifica a primeira clausula, se for verdadeiro ele passa para a proxima, mas como não há um if e nem um while então ele retorna a clausula em vez do um bool?

Comment: @ViniciusMorais Mais ou menos isso. Ele usa o valor da última cláusula como se fosse um boolean, mesmo que não seja. Há um comportamento análogo com o `||` também.

Answer (score 3):

Este comportamento é chamado de *Short-Circuit Evaluation* ou Avaliação de Curto-Circuito ([Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito) e [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)), que significa basicamente: "Se eu já consigo saber a resposta, nem vou verificar adiante".

Pegue como exemplo as tabelas-verdade de um AND e um OR:

```
+---------+-------+-------+  +---------+-------+-------+
|           AND           |  |            OR           |
+---------+-------+-------+  +---------+-------+-------+
|     entrada     | saída |  |     entrada     | saída |
+---------+-------+-------+  +---------+-------+-------+
| false   | false | false |  | false   | false | false |
| false   | true  | false |  | false   | true  | true  |
| true    | false | false |  | true    | false | true  |
| true    | true  | true  |  | true    | true  | true  |
+---------+-------+-------+  +---------+-------+-------+
```

Podemos perceber que o `AND` só será verdadeiro se TODAS suas entradas forem verdadeiras, e o `OR` apenas será falso se TODAS suas entradas forem falsas. Então o interpretador não precisa saber o que vem depois de um `false && ...` pois já é sabido que o resultado é `false`.

Então quando temos:

```
obj.attr && doSomething(obj.attr)
```

Ele só vai executar a função `doSomething` se `obj.attr` for algum valor [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Truthy).

Bem como:

```
let valor = param || default;
```

A variável `valor` vai receber o primeiro valor [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Truthy) que ela encontrar, da esquerda para a direita. Se não encontrar nenhum, vai ser o último valor (nesse caso `default`);

Answer (score 2):

A função [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) pega os valores do array e os usa como chave de entrada (qualquer palavra digitada) e mapeia todos para o mesmo valor (a pizza).

O end (`'' && word`) serve para não imprimir nada quando a chave de entrada do `map` for uma string vazia. Se `word` houver um valor (pois a pizza sempre tem um valor), será atribuído o valor da última variável avaliada (no caso dessa frase, `word`). Se a pizza vem por último, é ela que vai.

É um "[curto circuito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)"